# how to add an attribute to a button with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button that displays "Search", On the click of the button, I want the text to change to "searching" and add a spinning animation beside it.

Here is the HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " id="search" data- 
loading-text="<i class='fa-spin fas fa-circle-notch'> 
</i>Searching">Search
</button>
```

Here's my Jquery

```
$('button#search').click(function() {
$(this).text("Searching");
});
```

The text changes, but I want to add the animation. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: The fact that you were warned when making the question that a codepen without code is not allowed, and then you put text in a code block to get around it, earns an immediate down vote from me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this : 
it will take a little change the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".pushme").click(function () {
       $(this).text("DON'T PUSH ME");
    });
    
    $(".pushme-with-color").click(function () {
       $(this).text("DON'T PUSH ME");
       $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
       $(this).removeClass("btn-warning");
    });
    

    $(".pushme2").click(function(){
  $(this).text(function(i, v){
     return v === 'PUSH ME' ? 'PULL ME' : 'PUSH ME'
  });
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<section>
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="row text-center">
    <button class='btn btn-warning pushme'>PUSH ME</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    </div>
    </span>

</div>

</section>
</body>
```